# Copy value from one field to another in large list

Tags: list, powershell, rest

I have a larger list (~6000 items) that I want to copy values from one field to another.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I'm guessing there is a REST or PowerShell way, but only have limited experience with either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Datasheet-View and make Copy+Paste

or this Powershell script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
[System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("SiteURL”)

$web =  Get-SPWeb -Identity siteURL

$lista =$web.Lists["ListName"]

$items = $lista.items


foreach ($item in $items) {
  $user = $item["Source column"]

  write-host $useracc 

$useracc =  $web.EnsureUser( $user); 

$item["Desination column"] = $useracc

write-host $useracc

$item.update()
}

$lista.update()
```

http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/powershell-script-to-copy-column-items-for-one-column-to-20575.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This script looks like a direct copy from this page
[Powershell script to copy a value from one field to another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130294/powershell-script-to-copy-a-value-from-one-field-to-another)

As noted on that page this script will fail unless the value in the source column are actual user accounts.
The poster here has not mentioned user accounts so this line: $useracc =  $web.EnsureUser( $user); 
Needs to be removed